# Can't add a CButtonColumn to CGridView

Tags: php, yii, cgridview

I'm trying to create a custom `CGridView` column with delete button inside. I use `CArrayDataProvider` as a data container. But there is nothing on the screen when I run the code below..

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id' => 'my-model-grid',
    'dataProvider' => $arrayDataProvider,
    'columns' => array(
        'name',
        'email',
        array(
           'class'=>'zii.widgets.grid.CButtonColumn', 
        )
    )
));
```

If I delete this part:

```
array(
    'class'=>'zii.widgets.grid.CButtonColumn', 
)
```

it will work.

I render `CGridView` to `CJuiTab` using AJAX.

Comment: Does your error reporting is turned on?

Comment: Yes, it is.. The server answers with code 500 if i change the tab in CJuiTab

Comment: From chrome console: GET http://widgen/project/requests/1 500 (Internal Server Error)

Answer (score -1):

You can customize button 2 ways.
Remove the buttons whatever you want to remove.

**First**

```
array
(
    'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
    'template'=>'{delete}',
)
```

**Second (For more customize to link)**

```
  array(
        'class'             => 'CButtonColumn',
        'buttons'           => array(

            // Update
            'update'    => array('url' => '$this->grid->controller->createUrl("/agreement/update", array("id"=>$data->primaryKey))'),

            // View
            'view' => array('url' => '$this->grid->controller->createUrl("/agreement/".$data->primaryKey)'),

            // Delete
            'delete' =>
                array('url' => '$this->grid->controller->createUrl("/agreement/delete/".$data->primaryKey)'),

        ),
    ),
```

Comment: @SergeySikachev have you tried it using only array('class'=>'CButtonColumn')

Comment: I've tried and accepted the same result, so the problem is in CButtonColumn as i understand

Comment: @SergeySikachev what result did you get?

Comment: @SergeySikachev I am unable to find the issue. Share some other error if found.

Comment: @SergeySikachev Have you found the solution?

Comment: It works good now with CJuiTabs. It's smth like a magic.. Thank you very much

Comment: Can you let me know what was the issue?